# Android Studio IDE does not show Persian texts correctly in Windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, windows-10

I had Android Studio 2.2.3 on windows 7 and it was OK for Persian language.

Now I have installed Android Studio 2.2.3 on Windows 10 and I have problem with Persian (RTL or Arabic) characters in IDE environment.

What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think there's nothing wrong with the output but if you want to solve it in editor environment follow the steps below:

1- Close the Android Studio.

2- Go to the Android Studio install location, then go to bin folder.

3- Open `idea.properties` file with notepad or other editors.

4- Go to the last line and press enter, then add `editor.new.rendering=true` line and save file.

5- Open the Android Studio.